# How to do I pass self as a method parameter ?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I need to pass self into a method, how do I do it ?

I don't know what type of object self is ?

I've tried `:(id)dg`

Comment: What's the outcome of specifying it as `(id)`? How are you calling the method?

Comment: Why don't you know the class of self? Isn't that code in the same class?! *id* should work though, as probably does *NSObject **.

Comment: You might want to use more descriptive names than *db*. You'll thank yourself later when you have to fix a bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are inside an `@implementation` block for a class `Foo`, `self` is `Foo*`. This means that you can type the method parameter as `Foo*` or `id` (= any object, no type checking done):

```
@class Foo, SomeCollaborator;

@interface SomeCollaborator
- (void) doSomethingWithMe: (Foo*) myself;
- (void) doSomethingWithMe2: (id) myself;
@end

@implementation Foo
- (void) someFooMethod {
    [someCollaborator doSomethingWithMe:self];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

That seems right to me. (id) represents all possible objects.

Here's some code that works:

```
@implementation Inspector
- (void)printClassOf:(id)instance {
    NSLog("instance is of class: %@", [instance class]);
}
@end

@implementation SomeClass
- (void)someMethod {
    Inspector *myInstance = [[[Inspector alloc] init] autorelease];
    [myInstance printClassOf:self];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the signature of the method (in other words, how is the method defined in the interface)?

Or do you mean, you want to define a method in class B to allow an instance of class A to call that method and pass in itself as one of the parameters? If so, :(id)sender is often used as a generic way to do that. For example, in NSWindow,

```
- (void)makeKeyAndOrderFront:(id)sender;
- (void)orderFront:(id)sender;
- (void)orderBack:(id)sender;
```

Within the implementation of that method, you can do something like this to help determine what to do:

```
- (void)makeKeyAndOrderFront:(id)sender {
   if ([sender isKindOfClass:[NSWindowController class]]) {
     // do something 

   } else if ([sender isKindOfClass:[MyCoolClass class]]) {
     // do something 

   } else if ([sender respondsToSelector:@selector(whyDidYouOrderMeFront)]) {
     // do something 

   } else if ([sender conformsToProtocol:@protocol(someCoolProtocol)]) {
     // do something 

   } else {
     // do something 
   }
}
```